# Swift Thread 1: signal SIGART error after adding a new delegate

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates

I’m new to Swift and have been stuck on this problem for a while.

I’m trying to add a ‘settings’ view where the size of the font can be updated for the main view.

I get a `Thread 1: signal SIGART` error on the line: `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate`

After adding the below code, my app now crashes when I press on the settings button.

Not sure how else to debug this problem, any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

**View Controller:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, SettingsViewControllerDelegate {

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SettingsViewController" {
        let settingsViewController = segue.destination as? SettingsViewController
        if let viewController = settingsViewController {
            viewController.delegate = self
        }
    }
  }


  func makeChangesToFont(size: Int) {
    if (self.distanceReading.font.pointSize > 20) {
        self.distanceReading.font = UIFont(name: self.distanceReading.font.fontName, size: CGFloat(size))
    }
  }
...
}
```

**Settings Controller:**

```
import UIKit

protocol SettingsViewControllerDelegate {
func makeChangesToFont(size: Int)
}

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

  var delegate: SettingsViewControllerDelegate?

  @IBAction func IncreaseSize(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("something")
    increaseFontSize()
  }

  func increaseFontSize() {
    let mainView = parent as! ViewController
    let text = mainView.distanceReading
    let fontSize = (text?.font.pointSize)! + 10
    print(fontSize)

    if let delegate = self.delegate {
        delegate.makeChangesToFont(size: Int(fontSize))
    }
  }
...
}
```

I'm using Swift 3 in Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: Show your console log here.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni nothing appears in the console log

Comment: Can you share sample project?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Share demo project and I will try it from my side and if I am able to replicate I can give a solution if possible.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same issue with just _adding the above code_. The actual cause of the crash may reside in `...` where you are hiding, or somewhere in the storyboard settings. Without showing more info, no one can solve your issue.